# Python Abaqus: Index in the sequence is out of range

Tags: python, abaqus

I have written a code for a half sphere which has a hole in it. When I run the code in abaqus it shows several warnings pertaining to the fact that index sequence is out of range. I have tried everything and am unable to find the error. Can someone please help.

One part of the code:
enter code here

```
t = 1.0; # shell thickness
Re = 40.0 # radius 
Ri = 5.0 # hole radius
o = 30; # number of points to define cap
A = 10.0; # cap apex height
d = 1.8*A # actuated distance
th = 2*math.pi;
meshsize=1.3;

  

m=mdb.models['Model-1']
s=mdb.models['Model-1'].ConstrainedSketch(name='__profile__', sheetSize=200.0)
s.ConstructionLine(point1=(0.0, -100.0), point2=(0.0, 100.0))
s.FixedConstraint(entity=s.geometry[2])
# sphere cap
n = np.linspace(start=1, stop=th, num=128, endpoint=False)
x = [Re*(math.cos(th*float(i)))+(Ri+(float(i))) for i in (n)];
y = [Re*(math.sin(th*float(i))) for i in (n)];
w = np.int_(x)
z = np.int_(y)
points=[];
l = len(n);
for i in (n):
    points.append([w[i], z[i]])
    
s.Spline(points=points)
p=m.Part(dimensionality=THREE_D, name='structure', type=DEFORMABLE_BODY)
p.BaseShellRevolve(angle=360.0, flipRevolveDirection=OFF,sketch=s)
del s
```

Comment: Please post the error traceback so that we see the source of error.

Answer (score 0):

This part of the code runs on my machine without error.

Why are you using a spline to approximate an arc? I recommend you create the geometry manually and then inspect the resulting abaqus.rpy file for the Python commands.